# how to fix UnsatisfiedDependencyException in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am new in spring framework. i was doing bellow code according to a tutorial. but it giving me errors. it's showing me required a single bean, but 2 were found. but i am using @Qualifier and it should work. i have used @primary and that works fine.
but only for @Qualifier and autowiring by name are not working for me.

/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.arman.spring.basics</groupId>
<artifactId>spring_project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring_project</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

BubbleSortAlgorithm.java class

```
package com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Qualifier("bubble")

public class BubbleSortAlgorithm implements SortAlgorithm {

public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
    return numbers;
}
}
```

QuickSortAlgorithm.java

```
package com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Qualifier("quick")
public class QuickSortAlgorithm implements SortAlgorithm {
public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
    return numbers;
}
}
```

SortAlgorithm.java interface

```
package com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project;
public interface SortAlgorithm {
public int[] sort(int[] numbers);

}
```

BinarySearchImpl.java class

```
package com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component

public class BinarySearchImpl {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("quick")
private SortAlgorithm bubbleSortAlgorithm;

public BinarySearchImpl(SortAlgorithm sortAlgorithm) {
    this.bubbleSortAlgorithm = sortAlgorithm;
}

public SortAlgorithm getSortAlgorithm() {
    return bubbleSortAlgorithm;
}

public void setSortAlgorithm(SortAlgorithm sortAlgorithm) {
    this.bubbleSortAlgorithm = sortAlgorithm;
}

public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int numberToSearchFor) {

    int[] sortedNumbers = bubbleSortAlgorithm.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(bubbleSortAlgorithm);
    // search the array

    return 3;
}

}
```

SpringProjectApplication.java class that contains main class

```
package com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringProjectApplication {

// what are the beans?
// what are the dependency of a bean?
// where to search for them?

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * BinarySearchImpl binarySearch= new BinarySearchImpl(new
     * QuickSortAlgorithm());
     */
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringProjectApplication.class);
    BinarySearchImpl binarySearchImpl = applicationContext.getBean(BinarySearchImpl.class);
    BinarySearchImpl binarySearchImpl2 = applicationContext.getBean(BinarySearchImpl.class);

    System.out.println(binarySearchImpl2);
    System.out.println(binarySearchImpl);

    int result = binarySearchImpl.binarySearch(new int[] { 12, 13, 10, 1, 3 }, 3);
    System.out.println(result);
}

}
```

logs of that application.

```
2019-02-06 23:25:33.265  INFO 11068 --- [           main] c.a.s.b.s.SpringProjectApplication       : Starting SpringProjectApplication on DESKTOP-JDRMFHT with PID 11068 (C:\Users\Arman\git\spring-practice\spring_project\target\classes started by Arman in C:\Users\Arman\git\spring-practice\spring_project)
2019-02-06 23:25:33.275  INFO 11068 --- [           main] c.a.s.b.s.SpringProjectApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-06 23:25:33.382  INFO 11068 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@90c451: startup date [Wed Feb 06 23:25:33 BDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-06 23:25:34.687  WARN 11068 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'binarySearchImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Arman\git\spring-practice\spring_project\target\classes\com\arman\spring\basics\spring_project\BinarySearchImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project.SortAlgorithm' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: bubbleSortAlgorithm,quickSortAlgorithm
2019-02-06 23:25:34.705  INFO 11068 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-06 23:25:34.715 ERROR 11068 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project.BinarySearchImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - bubbleSortAlgorithm: defined in file [C:\Users\Arman\git\spring-practice\spring_project\target\classes\com\arman\spring\basics\spring_project\BubbleSortAlgorithm.class]
    - quickSortAlgorithm: defined in file [C:\Users\Arman\git\spring-practice\spring_project\target\classes\com\arman\spring\basics\spring_project\QuickSortAlgorithm.class]
```

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Answer (score 0):

You are using @Qualifier in wrong way. Set bean name in @Component directly:

```
@Component("bubble")
public class BubbleSortAlgorithm implements SortAlgorithm {
public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
    return numbers;
}
}

@Component("quick")
public class QuickSortAlgorithm implements SortAlgorithm {
public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
    return numbers;
}
}
```

---

Yes, you are right. The problem with constructor. It is not clear for spring what you want to autowire. Autowiring with constructor has priority.

So you BinarySearchImpl should looks like:

```
private SortAlgorithm bubbleSortAlgorithm;

public Test(@Qualifier("quick") SortAlgorithm sortAlgorithm) {
    this.bubbleSortAlgorithm = sortAlgorithm;
}
```

or without constructor.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("quick")
private SortAlgorithm bubbleSortAlgorithm;
```

Comment: no sir, still same errors occuring. just the log changed a little bit.
\
No qualifying bean of type 'com.arman.spring.basics.spring_project.SortAlgorithm' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: bubble,quick